# Optimizing Image Hash Search Query

Tags: sqlite, optimization, hash, query-optimization

I've managed to develop a query that returns similar images from a database of hashes.

The rows consist of a path to the image, as well as 64 columns of bits representing the image hash. The query works by comparing each bit of the target image against the images in the database, returning the sum of matched bits, and then selecting the path if the number of matches is above a thresh hold.

```
SELECT path FROM duplicatesCheck
WHERE (
    SELECT (left1=right1) + ... + (left64=right64)
    FROM 
    (SELECT hash1 AS left1, ... hash64 AS left64
    FROM duplicatesCheck WHERE path=path),
    (SELECT hash1 AS right1, ... hash64 AS right64
    FROM duplicatesCheck WHERE path=?)
) >= 55
```

However, the query is very convoluted, at ~3.6 thousand characters. I'm wondering if there's a better way to query this. I've tried using joins and views but haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: If this is a query that you will do often, it would be much more efficient to have a binary tree of hashes of all your images in memory and match a hash against it

Comment: So each column is one bit, and you want those rows where at least 55 bits match? Could you store all bits in one column, then use the [SQLite replacement for xor](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/XOR-operator-td98004.html), convert that to a [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281580/is-there-any-way-to-convert-an-integer-3-in-decimal-form-to-its-binary-equival) where '0' is '' and '1' is '1', then check the length... But the bigger question is, is it fast enough? Wouldn't you rather want to use locality sensitive hashing?